# button tag alway disabled in index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, phonegap-build

I am working on a Phonegap Build app for Android. I created two buttons with onclick which triggers a `doHelper` function that will disable the buttons after. But for some reason the buttons are always disabled even before clicking on the buttons.

Here is my code.

html:

```
 <div class="gameHelper">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="twelve columns">
         <button  onclick="doHelper('skip')" class="skipAnswer button helperButtons">
             Skip
         </button>

         <button onclick="doHelper('remove')" class="removeOneAnswer button helperButtons">
              Remove 1
          </button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

js:

```
function doHelper(helperName) {

    if (helperName == 'skip') {

        var classVar = '.skipAnswer';
        skipAnswerUsed = true;
        $(classVar).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(classVar).css('background-color', 'red');
        submitAnswer(activeNumber);

    } else if (helperName == 'remove') {
        var classVar = '.removeOneAnswer';
        removeOneAnswerUsed = true;
        $(classVar).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(classVar).css('background-color', 'red');
    }

}
```

css:

```
.helperButtons {
    width: 49%;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: can you add the css for .skipAnswer if there is any?

Comment: @user2033402 no i do not have any for the class, i just added it to the button classes for future uses like this one

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend seperating the **HTML** from your **JS**.

This can be done with event handlers. Since you are already using jQuery, here is one possible way to do that:

```
$('button.skipAnswer').on('click', function () {
   doHelper("skip");
});

$('button.removeOneAnswer').on('click', function () {
   doHelper("remove");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jczt3uu/

Answer (score 2):

Are you using firefox? Probably that is the problem, I had the same issue some time ago...

You can fix it by adding

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML and Javascript is correct. There is probably another issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to this way

```
function doHelper(helperName) {
                    $('button').removeAttr('disabled')
                    $('button').css('background-color', '');
                    if (helperName == 'skip') {

                        var classVar = '.skipAnswer';
                        skipAnswerUsed = true;
                        $(classVar).attr('disabled', '');
                        $(classVar).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(classVar).css('background-color', 'red');
                        submitAnswer(activeNumber);

                    } else if (helperName == 'remove') {

                        var classVar = '.removeOneAnswer';
                        $(classVar).attr('disabled', '');
                        removeOneAnswerUsed = true;
                        $(classVar).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(classVar).css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
                }
```